# Sorting algorithm to implement highest total combinations

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm interested in learning what algorithm would be best suited to solve the following problem. Here's the criteria.

I have a list of players. Each player has three attributes.

- Team
- Value
- Position

Each team has roughly 20 players. Let's say we're talking baseball here and the positions are `1B`, `2B`, `3B`, `SS`, `C`, `OF`.

What I'm interested in doing is sorting for the top `N` combinations, where `N > 0` of the highest combined value for `4` team mates.

So each combination of `4 players` has to be on the same team. Each combination of `4 players` should have a higher total combined `Value` then every subsequent combination.

The one restriction is that every position can be used only once per combination, except for `OF` which can be used up to three times in one combination of 4 players.

So in the following pool of made up players, I'll show the top 2 combinations:

```
Team Toronto
Player 1, SS, 1.0
Player 2, 1B, 1.0
Player 3, 1B, 2.0
Player 4, 2B, 2.0
Player 5, 3B, 4.0
Player 6, 3B, 3.0
Player 7, C, 4.0
Player 8, OF, 1.0
Player 9, OF, 2.0
Player 10, OF, 5.0
Player 11, OF, 6.0

Team Washington
Team Toronto
Player 1, SS, 3.0
Player 2, 1B, 2.0
Player 3, 1B, 1.0
Player 4, 2B, 2.0
Player 5, 3B, 2.0
Player 6, 3B, 3.0
Player 7, C, 7.0
Player 8, OF, 1.0
Player 9, OF, 2.0
Player 10, OF, 2.0
Player 11, OF, 3.0
```

The highest projected combo would be

```
Team Toronto: 
   * Player 11
   * Player 10
   * Player 7
   * Player 5
```

total value of `19.0`

The second highest projected combo would also be Team Toronto with

```
* Player 11
* Player 10
* Player 7
* Player 6
```

with a total of `18.0`

Team Washington's highest combo is Player 1, Player 6, Player 7 and Player 11, and their value is only `16.0` so they wouldn't show up until later in the sort.

What's the best algorithm to handle this in an efficient fashion if say I'm dealing with a pool of 500 players daily (distributed over 10 or more teams)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) for this. As the heuristic function, take the cost of the players already selected plus the maximum cost of the remaining players needed to complete the team.

Here's some Python code. First, the setup:

```py
def split(team):
    return [(x.strip(), y.strip(), float(z)) for x, y, z 
            in (line.split(",") for line in team.splitlines())]

team1 = ("Toronto",
        split("""Player 1, SS, 1.0
        Player 2, 1B, 1.0
        Player 3, 1B, 2.0
        Player 4, 2B, 2.0
        Player 5, 3B, 4.0
        Player 6, 3B, 3.0
        Player 7, C, 4.0
        Player 8, OF, 1.0
        Player 9, OF, 2.0
        Player 10, OF, 5.0
        Player 11, OF, 6.0"""))

team2 = ("Washington",
        split("""Player 1, SS, 3.0
        Player 2, 1B, 2.0
        Player 3, 1B, 1.0
        Player 4, 2B, 2.0
        Player 5, 3B, 2.0
        Player 6, 3B, 3.0
        Player 7, C, 7.0
        Player 8, OF, 1.0
        Player 9, OF, 2.0
        Player 10, OF, 2.0
        Player 11, OF, 3.0"""))

teams = [team1, team2]
```

We also need a function to tell whether a certain combination is valid. We do not need to check that no player appears twice, as they will be unique by construction, so we just have how often each of the player positions appear.

```py
ALLOWED = {"1B": 1, "2B": 1, "3B": 1, "SS": 1, "C": 1, "OF": 3}

def legal(players):
    d = {}
    for p in players:
        d[p[1]] = d.get(p[1], 0) + 1
    return all(d[x] <= ALLOWED[x] for x in d)
```

Now for the interesting part: The A* search. We are using a [heap, or priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), each entry in the heap being a tuple `(estimated_cost, players, position)`, so the (partial) team with the highest total estimated cost will be first in the heap (we use `-cost`, as the heap will be sorted from least to greatest). `pos` tells us our current position in the list of players, sorted by individual cost, highest first.

We then pop the next element from the heap, check whether it's a solution, and either `yield` the result<sup>1)</sup>, or add another player to the team, updating the estimated cost with the cost of the current team, filled up with the next-expensive players from the bulk of remaining players (`new_players + team_players[i+1:i+more_needed]`), and add that combination to the heap.

```py
def generator(team_players, num):
    team_players = sorted(team_players, key=lambda p: p[2], reverse=True)
    queue = [(-sum(p[2] for p in team_players[:num]), [], 0)]
    while queue:
        estimated_cost, players, pos = heapq.heappop(queue)
        more_needed = num - len(players)
        if not more_needed:
            yield estimated_cost, players
        else:
            for i in range(pos, len(team_players) - more_needed + 1):
                player = team_players[i]
                new_players = players + [player]
                if legal(new_players):
                    estimate = -sum(p[2] for p in new_players + team_players[i+1:i+more_needed])
                    heapq.heappush(queue, (estimate, new_players, i+1))
```

Finally, we have a second generator function, mapping the above generators to team name and generating the next-best solution for each team (if any) one after another. Another heap is used to store the currently best solutions for each team, sorted by total cost.

```py
def generate_all(teams):
    generators = {name: generator(players, 4) for name, players in teams}
    best_teams = [(next(generators[name]), name) for name in generators]
    heapq.heapify(best_teams)
    while best_teams:
        team, name = heapq.heappop(best_teams)
        yield name, team
        try:
            heapq.heappush(best_teams, (next(generators[name]), name))
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

Now just generate and print the first few from that generator:

```py
all_teams_generator = generate_all(teams)
for _ in range(10):
    print(next(all_teams_generator))
```

Output in format `(team-name, (-cost, [(player1), ..., (player4)]))`:

```py
('Toronto', (-19.0, [('Player 11', 'OF', 6.0), ('Player 10', 'OF', 5.0), ('Player 5', '3B', 4.0), ('Player 7', 'C', 4.0)]))
('Toronto', (-18.0, [('Player 11', 'OF', 6.0), ('Player 10', 'OF', 5.0), ('Player 7', 'C', 4.0), ('Player 6', '3B', 3.0)]))
('Toronto', (-17.0, [('Player 11', 'OF', 6.0), ('Player 10', 'OF', 5.0), ('Player 5', '3B', 4.0), ('Player 3', '1B', 2.0)]))
('Toronto', (-17.0, [('Player 11', 'OF', 6.0), ('Player 10', 'OF', 5.0), ('Player 5', '3B', 4.0), ('Player 4', '2B', 2.0)]))
('Toronto', (-17.0, [('Player 11', 'OF', 6.0), ('Player 10', 'OF', 5.0), ('Player 5', '3B', 4.0), ('Player 9', 'OF', 2.0)]))
('Toronto', (-17.0, [('Player 11', 'OF', 6.0), ('Player 10', 'OF', 5.0), ('Player 7', 'C', 4.0), ('Player 3', '1B', 2.0)]))
('Toronto', (-17.0, [('Player 11', 'OF', 6.0), ('Player 10', 'OF', 5.0), ('Player 7', 'C', 4.0), ('Player 4', '2B', 2.0)]))
('Toronto', (-17.0, [('Player 11', 'OF', 6.0), ('Player 10', 'OF', 5.0), ('Player 7', 'C', 4.0), ('Player 9', 'OF', 2.0)]))
('Toronto', (-16.0, [('Player 11', 'OF', 6.0), ('Player 10', 'OF', 5.0), ('Player 5', '3B', 4.0), ('Player 1', 'SS', 1.0)]))
('Toronto', (-16.0, [('Player 11', 'OF', 6.0), ('Player 10', 'OF', 5.0), ('Player 5', '3B', 4.0), ('Player 2', '1B', 1.0)]))
```

---

*Addendum: On Performance.* For small teams, generating all the combinations and picking the best ones, as in [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30790643/1639625), is probably indeed "good enough", and certainly much simpler. However, this version, using A*, can be a good deal faster and might be worth a try if you have larger teams, or a greater number of different teams, or if you have to do this very often. Here's some timing information, generating the top ten teams using both algorithms.

```py
>>> timeit.timeit("allcomb.main(10)", "import allcomb", number=1000)
6.20834589005
>>> timeit.timeit("astar.main(10)", "import astar", number=1000)
1.55367398262
```

Note that this is for 1000 iterations, so for a single iteration, both algorithms will need just a few milliseconds. Also note that due to the generative nature of the A*, it is much faster the fewer combinations you need. For just the best combination, it's six times faster, and for the top ten, it's four times faster, but if you want *all* the combinations anyway, the A* is in fact three times *slower* than just generating all the combinations in the first place.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Note that this is using generator functions, which are pretty unique to Python, but you can do the same using a class encapsulating the queue as a member and providing a method, returning the next valid solution. If you are interested, I could also rewrite it that way.

Answer (score 7):

You can sort players in decreasing order in each team and then iterate throw sorted list. Code can look something like this:

```
int highestCombinedValue = 0, i = 0, currentNumber = 0, count1B = 0, count2B = 0, cpunt3B = 0, countSS =0, countC = 0, countOF = 0;
while(currentNumber < 4 && list.get(i) != null)
{
  currentPlayer = list.get(i);
  switch currentPlayer.position
  {
    case: 1B
    then if(count1B < 1)
    {
      highestCombinedValue = highestCombinedValue + currentPlayer.value;
      count1B = count1B + 1;
    }
    break;
    case: 2B
    ...
    case: OF
    then if(count1B < 3)
    {
      highestCombinedValue = highestCombinedValue + currentPlayer.value;
      count1B = count1B + 1;
    }
    break;
  }
  i = i + 1;
}
```

You can store team with result in list and sort this result list in decreasing order to obtain top teams.

Comment: +1, this simple approach gives the optimal solution in O(n log n) time.  But mention that the players need to be sorted *in decreasing value order* within each team.

Comment: But does this also work for finding the top `n` combinations per team, as requested in the question, or just for the single best one? Also, I don't think this could be extended to different constraints, e.g. "if one of this type is selected, then none of that other type are allowed". As I understand it, Baseball was just an example.

Comment: As I understood top N combination must be found for all teams and according to example it will be combinations from different teams, but better ask author of the question.

Comment: How would you get the second highest combo for Toronto with this approach?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is not as complicated as you think. Use a bit of mathematical inference to simplify your problem.

1. Sort each team in decreasing score value. A quick and easy way is to put the team members into a max heap.
2. To find the highest scoring combination in each team, pop the heap 4 times and add up the values of those 4 nodes. This is your max combination.

Worst case complexity is O(n^2).

To generalize this to top n, pop top 3, sum, then for each item left, pop that item, sum it, and stick in another max heap to keep this list sorted. Continue down the list by repeating the same for top-1 node in the original heap.

Comment: The only thing this is missing is how to handle the case in which the top 4 (or more) highest-scoring players within a team are OF.  But this is also trivial to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Given a team size of 20, there are only  `20*19*18*17/(4*3*2*1) = 4845` combinations of 4 players from the team (not all of which are legal) so you should be able to simply brute force all possible team combinations, sort, and select the highest scoring ones.

Here is some example Python code that does this for your example:

```
import itertools

def f(s):
    players = []
    for x in s.splitlines():
       player,pos,score = x.split(',')
       score=float(score)
       pos=pos.strip()
       players.append( (player,pos,score) )
    return players

teams={}

teams['Toronto'] = f("""Player 1, SS, 1.0
Player 2, 1B, 1.0
Player 3, 1B, 2.0
Player 4, 2B, 2.0
Player 5, 3B, 4.0
Player 6, 3B, 3.0
Player 7, C, 4.0
Player 8, OF, 1.0
Player 9, OF, 2.0
Player 10, OF, 5.0
Player 11, OF, 6.0""")

teams['Washington'] = f("""Player 1, SS, 3.0
Player 2, 1B, 2.0
Player 3, 1B, 1.0
Player 4, 2B, 2.0
Player 5, 3B, 2.0
Player 6, 3B, 3.0
Player 7, C, 7.0
Player 8, OF, 1.0
Player 9, OF, 2.0
Player 10, OF, 2.0
Player 11, OF, 3.0""")

def legal(comb):
    """Test if this is a legal team combination"""
    count_of = 0
    S = set()
    for player,pos,score in comb:
        if pos == 'OF':
            count_of += 1
        elif pos in S:
            return False
        else:
            S.add(pos)
    return count_of <= 3

A = [] # List of legal combinations
for team_name,players in teams.items():
    for comb in itertools.combinations(players,4):
        if legal(comb):
            score = sum(p[2] for p in comb)
            A.append( (score,comb,team_name) )
A.sort(reverse = True)
for score,comb,team_name in A[:2]:
    print score,team_name,comb
```

Comment: I'm going to attempt to translate this to Ruby and see how it goes.

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this approach, but according to this: "I'm dealing with a pool of 500 players daily (distributed over 10 or more teams)" there might be on average 50 players on a team. Probably, those 200k combos (if the players are evenly distributed) aren't much of a problem either, just wanted to point out...

Answer (score 1):

Finding all combinations within each team as suggested by @Peter de Rivaz is certainly the easiest to do correctly. I included Ruby code as a baseline for testing something more sophisticated.

But it turns out you can apply a simple greedy algorithm to this problem. So the A* and other search propositions are overkill. Hill climbing is enough.  I'm still not sure it's worth the trouble with your data size. I won't have time to code it. That wouldn't be very hard, but there's significant bookkeeping, and edge cases (like players and combinations with exactly equal values) must be handled with care.

The argument for greediness goes like this:

> Proposition: Let `C = c_0, c_1, ..., c_N-1` be the combinations of 4 players arranged in decreasing order of total value. Then for each `1 <= i < N`, we can say that `c_i` can be formed by taking some `c_j`, `0 <= j < i` (a combination of higher value) and substituting exactly one of its four elements P with a different player Q of *minimally lower value*. By minimally lower value we mean there is no player with the same position as Q with higher value that is still lower than P's.
>
> The proof by contradiction is tedious, but pretty simple and I won't give it.

How to turn this into an algorithm?  The trick is that if we have any combination [A,B,C,D], the set of possible "next" combinations for the same team in sorted order is small. Just consider replacing each of the combo elements in U=[A,B,C,D] in succession with all possible "legal" players having minimally lower value. E.g, let next(P, pos) be the unique player with position pos having highest value lower than P. Let O be the set of all positions *not* in {pos(A),pos(B),pos(C),pos(D)}. Then the possible "successor" combinations in sorted order after [A,B,C,D] is just

```
succ(U) = next(A, pos(A)) union_(o\in O).next(A, o) union
          next(B, pos(B)) union_(o\in O).next(B, o) union
          next(C, pos(C)) union_(o\in O).next(C, o) union
          next(D, pos(D)) union_(o\in O).next(D, o)
```

So succ(U) contains a small finite number of elements. The algorithm just starts with the max value combination for each team, puts it in a priority queue, then repeatedly pulls a combination off the queue (this is the output), finds its possible successors, and adds them to the queue. It keeps a "visited" set to prevent adding an element multiple times.

It's possible to show - though I won't do it here - that the heap will  have at most O(n^3) elements on it, where n is the number of players on a team.  So the run time will be O(log n) per combination taken out of the heap. You can stop any time you like.

Here is pseudocode:

```
Let H be a priority queue with add and deleteMax operations.
for each team t
  P = sequence of players of t sorted in decreasing order of value
  Let Cmax = {}  # the maximum value combination for team t.
  for each player p in P
    if adding p to Cmax doesn't make it an invalid combo,
      add p to Cmax
      if |Cmax| == 4, break
  end for
  # Cmax is now the max value combination for t
  add Cmax to H
end for
# H is now initialized with the max val player of each team
Let V = {} # A set of visited combinations
while H is not empty
  let c = H.deleteMax
  output c
  Add succ(c) - V to H
  V = V union succ(c)
}
```

Sorry I don't have time right now to code this.  It would be fun.

Here's the "brute force" Ruby code:

```
Player = Struct.new('Player', :team, :name, :pos, :val)

# The algorithm.
def sorted_combos(data)
  data.map{|team| team.combination(4).select{|g| combination_ok? g } }
    .flatten(1).sort_by{|x| x.map(&:val).inject(&:+) }.reverse!
end

# Checking that a particular combination meets the membership rules.
def combination_ok?(g)
  not_of = g.map(&:pos).select{|x| x != 'OF'}
  not_of.size >= 1 && not_of.uniq.size == not_of.size
end


# Test.
def parse(teams)
  teams.map{|t| t[1].split("\n").map{|x| x.split(/,\s*/) }
    .map{|x| Player.new(t[0], x[0], x[1], x[2].to_f) } }
end

DATA = [
  ['Toronto',
   'Player 1, SS, 1.0
Player 2, 1B, 1.0
Player 3, 1B, 2.0
Player 4, 2B, 2.0
Player 5, 3B, 4.0
Player 6, 3B, 3.0
Player 7, C, 4.0
Player 8, OF, 1.0
Player 9, OF, 2.0
Player 10, OF, 5.0
Player 11, OF, 6.0'
  ],
  ['Washington',
  'Player 1, SS, 3.0
Player 2, 1B, 2.0
Player 3, 1B, 1.0
Player 4, 2B, 2.0
Player 5, 3B, 2.0
Player 6, 3B, 3.0
Player 7, C, 7.0
Player 8, OF, 1.0
Player 9, OF, 2.0
Player 10, OF, 2.0
Player 11, OF, 3.0'
  ],
]

print sorted_combos(parse(DATA))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve this problem by creating a graph that represents the possible player combinations. Then use an algorithm that computes the shortest paths for the graph and then sort the paths.

I think the [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm could work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your problem and the scale of which you've indicated to be a maximum (500) I would probably recommend a Quick Sort algorithm.

Quick sort ( `O (n log n )` ) essentially systematically iterates over every element and puts the sorted values into a new array. The worst case scenario for a quick sorting algorithm can be pretty bad when you get into the large datasets, but for yours it would be a matter of seconds, even at worst case `O(N^2)`.

Thinking bigger, you could look at a heap sort. A heap sort will divide your data structure into regions, and move things from one region into the other, starting at the highest first. I would only use this with larger amounts of data, because for the most part it's slower than a quick sort. However, the slowest that you're going to see on a heap sort is around `O(n log n)`, it's a lot more consistent.

Jake - Software Engineer

Comment: Fairly sure quick sort doesn't take into account positional requirements.

Comment: In what context are you issuing the sort, I.E, what programming language would you be implementing the sort with? I've never had any issues in sorting using quick sort - as long as your values are held by the same key within the object.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a single team for a moment. Since there are approximately 5000 different selections, but the top score seems to be around 20 (for the examples you gave), there are going to be a lot of combinations that give the same high score, an average of about 250 combinations for each score. For Toronto, the highest score (19) seems achievable in only one way, maybe 18 is achievable in one way or several ways, but the number will grow rapidly.

Sorting doesn't make so much sense in this context. You're going to have hundreds, or maybe thousands, of selections with the same score, so sorting them seems like a colossal waste of computer time when there's no criterion other than score for ranking one team higher than another.

I suggest you turn the problem around, and ask instead, "How many and which combinations give me a score of X with team Toronto?" For the max (19 in your example) there may be a single combination or a handful of combinations, but for numbers less than the max you'll get a whole bunch.

Let's say you're trying to build Toronto teams with a score of 16. First, you could put player 11 into the team. Then the problem would become one of finding a selection of 3 players that adds to 10 and has at most two OF. Then you could say player 11 isn't in but player 10 must be, etc. It's a knapsack type problem that could be solved by recursion (or if you have a lot of memory space available, a bottom up approach with tables). I think it would run quickly because the size of the selection is small. What would the approximate range of N be? If N is small enough you can stop well before you generate all the combinations.

Comment: **You're going to have hundreds, or maybe thousands, of selections with the same score**. Are you only thinking about integer? How does this make sense?

Comment: 5000 combinations per team, 10 teams = 50,000 combinations. If the values are integers from 4 to 20, that's only 16 values for 50,000 combinations. If the values can take on half integers as well, that's still only 30 values for 50,000 combinations. If the values can take on 1/10 integers (one decimal point), that's only 200 values for 50,000 combinations, or 250 for each value on average. To decide whether my suggestion is helpful, we need to know the range and precision of values, and the range of N.